# How to remove a complete node from XML in C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xmldocument, c#-7.0

I have `C#` application. Below is my XML

```
<subscription>
  <subscription_add_ons type="array">
    <subscription_add_on>
      <add_on_code>bike-o-vision</add_on_code>
      <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
    </subscription_add_on>
    <subscription_add_on>
      <add_on_code>boxx</add_on_code>
      <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
    </subscription_add_on>
  </subscription_add_ons>
</subscription>
```

What I need is if I pass string addOnCode = boxx, remove the complete node i.e.,

```
<subscription_add_on>
  <add_on_code>boxx</add_on_code>
  <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
</subscription_add_on>
```

Function

```
  XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

        XElement element = new XElement(
             "subscription_add_on",
             new XElement("add_on_code", "box"),
             new XElement("quantity",
             new XAttribute("type", "integer"),
        1
    )
);

  xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(element.Name).Remove();
```

But somehow it's not removing as desired.

How can I do this using XDocument ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your element has nothing to do with your document. It's just a "loose" element. You need to find the element inside the document and then remove it.

Comment: @PalleDue Agreed but how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify the elements you want to remove in the original document, and then call `.Remove()` on those.

Here, we're looking to find all elements inside the document of type "subscription_add_on", and then filtering to the ones which have a child called "add_on_code" which has the value "boxx". We then remove them all.

```
xmlDoc.Root
    .Descendants("subscription_add_on")
    .Where(x => x.Element("add_on_code").Value == "boxx")
    .Remove();
```

Note that `.Descendents()` will search down multiple levels (so it looks inside your "subscription_add_ons" element to find the "subscription_add_on" children), while `.Elements()` and `.Element()` only search down a single level.

See the [MSDN docs on linq2xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml), and in particular [Removing Elements, Attributes, and Nodes from an XML Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/removing-elements-attributes-and-nodes-from-an-xml-tree) .